# Training with keras using fragments of data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, training-data

I train a sequential model (20 dense layers) in keras (python) using default settings and just 1 epoch.
All layers are activated with relu, except the last on that uses sigmoid.

**METHOD A:**

Feed model with 1,000,000 records of labeled training data.

**METHOD B:**

1. Train model with 50,000 records
2. Save the model
3. Do some stuff
4. Load saved model
5. Train with another 50,000 records
6. Repeat until all 1,000,000 records are used

Why is there a discrepancy between the above 2 methods?

I always get better accuracy using all data at once, than using it in groups.

What is the reason for that?

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(30, input_dim = 27, activation = 'relu'))
...
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim = 10, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'sgd', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.load_weights(PreviousWeightsFile)
model.fit(X, Y, verbose = 0)
model.save_weights(WeightsFile)
(exit python and do some stuff)
```

Answer (score 1):

from the documentation, here the crucial model parameters for your question

> initial_epoch: Integer. Epoch at which to start training (useful for
>   resuming a previous training run).

and

> epochs: Integer. Number of epochs to train the model. An epoch is an
>   iteration over the entire x and y data provided. Note that in
>   conjunction with initial_epoch, epochs is to be understood as "final
>   epoch". The model is not trained for a number of iterations given by
>   epochs, but merely until the epoch of index epochs is reached.

You are not using these parameters therefore you are overwriting your weights and are not resuming training like you could with the `epochs` parameter.  That's the reason why your model always performs worse with method B.

Comment: I dont think that my weights are overwritten, since test accuracy follows an expected curve, similar to the other method. Also since i dont set the params you mentioned they always start with their default values, initial_epoch=0, epochs=1. That means that the model is always being trained for just 1 epoch.

Answer (score 0):

With all the data, the interactions between features and the resultant backpropagation will be more accurate with all present data; this allows for features and the architecture of the model to build upon additional epochs.

When you save and reload you essentially restart this.

Comment: But isn't backpropagation performed for each minibatch? The default batch_size is 32. Is backpropagation building up knowledge or just restarting between minibatches?